# Pointing domain to VPS webserver

Tags: vps, iis7, nameserver

I am hosting a webserver using IIS on my VPS and I have a domain through godaddy, how would I go about forward my domain to the webserver without mirroring the site using A records.

Comment: You may be confused about what DNS A records are.  They don't "mirror" anything.  They point a domain name at an IP address.

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant :P

Comment: Why would it be a problem to have the domain name point to your server?  That is how DNS works for all we sites.

Comment: Are you concerned about the IP address appearing (or not appearing) in your URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You said you would like to forward your domain, so go to GoDaddy's domain control center, click on the domain, look for where it says forwarding and then fill out the IP address of your VPS there. Also be sure to make sure the name servers are not set to custom but the default GoDaddy ones.

Comment: Also be sure not to select _Forward with Masking_, as that will just result in an iframe to your site - see this for more:  [Forwarding or Masking Your Domain Name](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name).